# Parsing Text File and Importing to a Table in HBase

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am new to HBase I have exported the table data in a TextFormat  to a text file in the following format .

72 6f 77 31     keyvalues={row1/cf:a/1444817478342/Put/vlen=6/ts=0}

Same data I want to import to the table ,I have tried by giving this file input to the Hbase import but it is expecting SequenceFile Format and tried to tweak the import by changing input format class to TextInputFormat but still not working.Any guide lines to achieve my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of export you can using java program to upload data.
Sample code:
public class HBaseDataInsert {
    Configuration conf;
    HTable hTable;
    HBaseScan hbaseScan;

```
public HBaseDataInsert() throws IOException {
    conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    hTable = new HTable(conf, "emp_java");
}

public void upload_transactionFile() throws IOException {

    String currentLine = null;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader("transactionsFile.csv"));
    while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(currentLine);
        String[] line = currentLine.split(",");
        Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(line[0] + "_" + line[1]));
        p.add(Bytes.toBytes("details"), Bytes.toBytes("Name"), Bytes.toBytes(line[0]));
        p.add(Bytes.toBytes("details"), Bytes.toBytes("id"), Bytes.toBytes(line[1]));
        p.add(Bytes.toBytes("details"), Bytes.toBytes("DATE"), Bytes.toBytes(line[2]));
        p.add(Bytes.toBytes("transaction details"), Bytes.toBytes("TRANSACTION_TYPE"), Bytes.toBytes(line[3]));

        hTable.put(p);
    }
    br.close();
    hTable.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Aman!but my export format is not csv as mentioned I given sample one line(72 6f 77 31 keyvalues={row1/cf:a/1444817478342/Put/vlen=6/ts=0}) which is scan output of the table which I exported ,I want to import the same that in a generic way that got exported.

Answer (score 0):

The Export and import, by default works with sequence file dumps. If your requirement is just to load from one table to other, assuming both have similar formats, you can use below commands. Ths input and output directories are HDFS directories.

$ bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export

$ bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Import